# Which collection has the Best access time to find item.Property from

Tags: c#, performance, collections

I should design a solution for best performance for searching through items from that collection.

The problem is: 
I have an type:

```
class MyType {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Sequence{ get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Enum MyEnum { get; set; }
    //.....
}
```

I have a collection with objects: `Collection<MyType>`.

I want to search in this `Collection<MyType>` by a specific member, for example by **Id**.

I've analyzed and decided that I would use a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` or a `HashSet<T>`.
Now, i have doubts. Which collection would give me the best results (concerning time) in terms of access time, when attempting to find elements by a specific member of **MyType**:

1. to use `Dictionary<int, MyType>` where the **key** is the **Id** member from **MyType**, and MyType is the whole object,
2. to use a `HashSet<MyType>` and to find in it by item.Id ...

Is is possible to set to the HashSet which item member should be considered like an Index in SQL ?

Comment: As far as i understood you'll always search for Id, right? Not other property sometimes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't specify an "index" for a `HashSet<T>`.
You want to use `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` in your scenario.

Comment: According to MSDN the `HashSet<T>` can be instanciated either by a contructor taking a `IEqualityComparer<T>` for key comparision, or `T` implements `System.IEquatable<T>` for key comparison. Will this "work" as an internal index? Besides this, I would prefer `Dictionary<>` too.

Comment: @jCoder: Yes, you could create an `IEqualityComparer<T>` that compares only the `Id` property or make `T` implement `IEquatable<T>`. But I don't really see the benefit in doing so when you can simply use `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`.

Comment: @jCoder: Nope, because you can still only check `.Contains`. If the hash was the same as the `Id`, you could check for an element with the same `Id` by passing in a fake object, but not actually extract it.

Answer (score 0):

HashSet should be used when you only need to know if an item is in a set... IE...

```
HashSet.Contains(item);
```

Dictionary should be used if you are getting items out of the dictionary and the Key is the index into that collection.  So in your example above... searching the dictionary for a particular name will have to walk the entire dictionary to find it.

So in your example you would use the following to use the Id property for fast lookups.

```
var myDictionary = new Dictionary<int, MyType>();

myDictionary.Add(myType.Id, myType);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand, in your case `Dictionary` will work faster. You can use `HashSet` as such collection, but to find item by id you should use linq and there will be no performance gains against `Dictionary`.

**But in all cases you should to profile code to know what realization is faster in concrete circumstances.**